# Encode special characters with UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, replace, sax

I have a String `Address: Mount Road (Back) [Contact-Ron] & give him the {data}`
I need to use SAX parser and it doesn't parse special characters, we need to replace them with UTF-8 characters. 
Example-- `&` is replaced with `&amp`.
Is there any way to replace special characters with their corresponding `UTF-8` characters without individually writing replace code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like the [Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4-java.lang.String-)
to decode HTML character code sequences to corresponding UTF-8 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/owasp/owasp-java-encoder. OWASP Java Encoder is easy to use and handles various safety issues.